# "Из Варшавских дневников" - это неполное предложение или подпись к цитате?

Tags: синтаксис

> Из Варшавских дневников В.Шпильмана: "На этот раз я осмелился..."

"Из Варшавских дневников" - это неполное предложение или подпись к цитате?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [ПОДПИСЬ](http://m.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C&all=x), -и; ж. 1. к Подписать (1-2 зн.). Бумаги для подписи. Отправить документы на п. 2. Фамилия, собственноручно поставленная под чем-л. (под каким-л. текстом, рисунком, картиной и т.п.). Поставить п. Собственноручная, чужая п. Приказ за подписью директора. Не принимать заявление без подписи. Поставить, заверить, подтвердить чью-л. п. Собирать подписи (вносить в ведомость, лист и т.п. подписи участников какого-л. мероприятия). 3. Надпись под чем-л., на чём-л. Подпись под рисунком.

Как видим, может быть подпись под рисунком, фотографией и т. п. Но нет такого выражения "подпись к цитате". Разве что цитата оформлена в виде плаката, а к нему прилагается подпись.